# Highcharts multiple yAxis not working on servlet api data

Tags: angular, servlets, charts, highcharts, dynamic-data

I am fetching data from servlet in my angular application in json format which contains 3 elements. I want to plot the 3rd element of the servlet response object as another axis because of the low values of the data.

Data format:

[see data format here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfB4i.png)

Here is what I've tried:

```
    yAxis: [
      {
      title: {
        text: 'No. of Requests'
      }
    },{
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    {
      opposite: true,
      title: {
        text: 'Success Rate'
      }
    }
  ],
    series: {
             [data.SuccessByMsgType.series[0],
              data.SuccessByMsgType.series[1],
              data.SuccessByMsgType.series[2]],
            }
```

Also, tried passing data as

```
series: data.SuccessByMsgType.series
```

Tried, `linkedTo` as:

```
yAxis: [
  {
  title: { text: 'No. of Requests' }
  },{
  title: { text: '' }
  },{
  opposite: true,
  linkedTo: 0,
  title: { text: 'Success Rate' }
  }
]
```

Tried passing `yAxis` key value pair to data, in the method where I get the data from api, like:

```
for all 3:

data.SuccessByMsgType.series[0]["yAxis"] = 0
data.SuccessByMsgType.series[1]["yAxis"] = 0
data.SuccessByMsgType.series[2]["yAxis"] = 1

for just 1:

data.SuccessByMsgType.series[2]["yAxis"] = 1
```

Also tried changing plot type to 'line'

```
data.SuccessByMsgType.series[2]["type"] = "line"
```

But that is also not working.
The chart is still rendering the 3rd data array with the first two. Its does not form a custom yAxis as it is supposed to (from 0-100 hopefully) for 3rd data set.

I am new to highcharts and angular, can anyone please help?
What can be going wrong here?

Comment: Hi @MM1122, What do you exactly want to achieve? You have created 3 y-axes, which one should be used for the series with index 2? I have created a simple example with your settings: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bL450wce/, could you adapt it to show the problem?

Comment: Your fiddle is the exact thing what I want to achieve. I think this has to do something with when is the data sent to chart. As I am fetching data from an api, I think it gets sent to the chart before i apply `data.SuccessByMsgType.series[2]["yAxis"] = 1`. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: While writing the above comment, I realized that I am passing the data before making axis adjustments. Silly mistakes. Thanks for going through all the trouble of fiddle